# QString::split(const QRegularExpression) issue

Tags: regex, qt, qregularexpression

My app downloads a HTML webpage source code and then try to exctract html lines (tr).
My code:

```
QStringList linesPage1 = page1.split(QRegularExpression("<tr.*>"));
```

But when I do this:

```
qDebug() << linesPage1;
```

I got this:

```
("<table width=\"1085\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">", "")
```

When I try this code, he finds 31 occurences:

```
qDebug() << page1.count(QRegularExpression("<tr.*>"));
```

I don't understand why he counts 31 occurences but on another hand, he doesn't split the string.

Comment: Please note that the part your are splitting will get **removed** from the string! Could you post how the string looks before splitting it?

Comment: The string is too big to be pasted here.
But it is a classical html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your regular expression. It tries to match a string that starts with `<tr` end ends with `>`. And it will look for the **longest appeareance** of that string. In your case, it will start with the first `<tr` and go until the end of the document (because HTML ends with a `>`).

To avoid this, use: `<tr[^>]*>`. This way it will only match the `<tr ...>`, because any string except of `>` is allowed in between.

Try to use webistes like https://regex101.com/#pcre to validate and test your regular expressions!

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399908) Simple counter-example: `<tr onhover="if(i > 0) alert(i);">hello world</tr>` -> first part would be `0) alert(i);">hello world`